# Incorporate Excel formula Names in Word Mail Merge document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have an Excel document with numerous constants defined in **Names**. For example:

```
  -------------------------------------------
 /  Edit Name                             ? X \
|--------------------------------------------- |
|                                              |
|   Name:      days_worked_yearly_minimum      |
|   Scope:     Workbook                        |
|   Comment:                                   |
|                                              |
|   Refers to: =180                            |
|                                              |
|                   --------    ----------     |
|                   |  OK  |    | Cancel |     |
 \                  --------    ----------    /
  -------------------------------------------
```

Without changing the Excel document, is there any way to incorporate those constants in a Mail Merged Word template referencing the Excel document?

(I'm aware I could insert a column for each constant in the table in my Excel document. I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Excel can generate a list of named ranges for you. Open a new worksheet, click the menu "Insert", "Names", "Paste" and select "Paste list" in the pop up window.

Next, you can base your mailmerge on this list.

If you want to automate this process, you could create a sub `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` with something like this (not tested):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("<<worksheet_name>>").Range("A1").Select
    Selection.ListNames
End Sub
```

This executes each and every time the workbook opens.